# Editing an item in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to build a little web app using local storage. I can add and delete items but editing items works to a certain point. Items edit as you would expect but when you update(refresh) the page I get an extra item and a null item. I think I'm almost there but can't get my head around this issue. Please see my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/willwebdesigner/786Qu/2/

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 

    var i = 0;
    var menuButtons = " <a class='delete' href='#'>delete</a> <a class='edit' href='#'>edit</a></li>";

    // Initial loading of tasks
    for( i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        $("#tasks").append("<li id='task-" + i +"'>" + localStorage.getItem('task-' + i) + menuButtons);
    }

    // Add a task
    $("#tasks-form").submit(function() {
        if ( $("#task").val() != "" ) {
            localStorage.setItem( "task-" + i, $("#task").val());
            $("#tasks").append("<li id='task-" +i +"'>"+localStorage.getItem("task-" + i) + menuButtons);
            $("#task-" + i).css('display', 'none');
            $("#task-" + i).slideDown();
            $("#task").val("");
            i++;
        }
        return false;
    });  

    // Remove a task      
    $(document).on("click", "#tasks li a.delete", function() {
        localStorage.removeItem($(this).parent().attr("id"));
        $(this).parent().slideUp('slow', function() { 
            $(this).remove(); 
        });
        // This part resets all the IDs
        for( i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            if( !localStorage.getItem("task-"+ i)) {
                localStorage.setItem("task-"+ i, localStorage.getItem('task-' + (i + 1) )); // Moves the id up a level
                localStorage.removeItem("task-"+ (i + 1) );  // Removes the id 1 up from the deleted item
            }
        }
    });

    // Edit a task
    $(document).on("click", "#tasks li a.edit", function() {

        var thisID = $(this).parent().attr("id");

        $(this).parent().html("<form><input class='taskEdit" + thisID + "' autofocus><input type='submit'></form>")
        .submit(function() {
             localStorage.removeItem("task-" + thisID);
             localStorage.setItem("task-" + thisID, $(".taskEdit" + thisID ).val());
             $(this).html(localStorage.getItem("task-" + thisID) + menuButtons);
             return false;
        });
    });

    // Reset all
    $("#reset").click(function() {
        localStorage.clear();                            
    });

});
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Look at edit section you are binding submit to li not form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While editing you are appending the prefix incorrectly so, all you have to do is stop prepending the prefix

```
// Edit a task
$(document).on("click", "#tasks li a.edit", function() {

  var thisID = $(this).parent().attr("id"); // this is task-0

  $(this).parent().html("<form><input class='taskEdit" + thisID + "' autofocus><input type='submit'></form>")
    .submit(function() {
      //localStorage.removeItem("task-" + thisID); // it becomes task-task-0
      //localStorage.setItem("task-" + thisID, $(".taskEdit" + thisID ).val());
      localStorage.setItem(thisID, $(".taskEdit" + thisID ).val());
      $(this).html(localStorage.getItem(thisID) + menuButtons);
      return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thankyou! I knew I wasn't too far off. This makes complete sense to me now.